# cpu usage per user

Tags: 14.04, memory-usage, top

When I type `lscpu` I can read of the number of CPUs on our server (56). We are a few people working on this server and I would like to see how many CPU's are being used per user.

When I run `top` I can see the total usage per process, is there a way to group it per user? I have a feeling that one user is invoking so many CPU's in her program that it slows down my jobs.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the sort field within `top` as follows:

1. Hit <kbd>f</kbd> to enter the field management screen
   [image: top field management]
2. Use the arrow keys to select the `USER` field
   [image: top user select]
3. Hit the <kbd>s</kbd> to select it
4. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> to return to the main `top` screen

---

Alternatively, you can just start `top` with the `-u` parameter to select only processes for a specific user e.g. `top -u steeldriver`

Answer (score 0):

First run this:

`USERNAME="abcd"
while true; do  echo $(date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S)","$(top -b -n 1 -u "$USERNAME" | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }');sleep 5; done|tee cpuusage.csv`

then you can use dygraph for display the usage. In this example I have 8 CPUs - so max usage is 800%.

[image: cpu usage example]

you can download this example here: true-informatics.de/cpuusage.zip
Use the code on your own risk !